# Exim4 on DebianWheezy: Rejected by RCPT Unrouteable address

Tags: linux, email-server, exim, debian-wheezy

Recently I updated the MX records on a domain1.com to point to domain2.com. Domain two is currently running exim4 and I would like it to relay mail for domain1. The problem is every time I send an email from say user@gmail.com to user@domain1.com I receive the following message:

Note: I am not using split config files

```
2015-01-12 14:49:42 H=mail-ig0-f178.google.com [209.85.213.178] F=<user@gmail.com> rejected RCPT <user@domain1.com>: Unrouteable address
```

I've tried following several online guides from people who had the same issue to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction? I've been working on this for a while now and have made no progress.

Edit: 
    I'm still fairly new to exim4 so I'm not quite sure what you mean by adding an IP address router on Domain2 to connect to Domain1. However I did manage to add domain1 to dc_relay_domains as wells in dc_relay_nets. My current /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf is as follows:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='domain1.com;localhost'
dc_local_interfaces='IP of eth0;IP of eth1'
dc_readhost='domain1.com'
dc_relay_domains='domain1.com;'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets='IP of domain1/24'
dc_smarthost='domain1.com:25'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your logs on Domain2.  Also check Domain1 logs to see if they are rejecting messages. They should tell you why traffic is being rejected.  Here are a  few steps to get things working.

- Add an IP address router on Domain2 to connect to Domain1.  Test and verify.
- Add Domain1 to the `dc_relay_domains` in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` on Domain2.  Test and verify from a remote server. (Domain1 may work.)
- This is the point at which it makes sense to move the MX records.
- Possibly configure domain1 to use domain2 as its smart host.
- Add domain1 to `dc_relay_nets` in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` on Domain2.  Test from Domain1.

After changing values in `update-exim4.conf.conf1` you will need to reload the Exim4 configuration.

IP Routing or even name based routing can be done with the file `/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts`.  Add line of the format `Domain1: mailserver.domain1` to this file.  For details see the output of `man exim4-config_files`.

You may need to modify how recipients are verified for domain1.  Normally, you want this to be a callout.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Add an IP address router on Domain2 to connect to Domain1?

Comment: @Jukodan I've added details to my response.  The `hubbed_hosts` file should be able do the routing for you.

Comment: I'm not using split config files so I assume these changes are made to /etc/exim4/exim.conf.template?

    `hubbed_hosts:
     debug_print = "R: hubbed_hosts for $domain"
     driver = manualroute
     domains = "${if exists{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
                   {partial-lsearch;CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}\
              fail}"
     same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  route_data = ${lookup{$domain}partial-lsearch{CONFDIR/hubbed_hosts}}
  transport = remote_smtp`

Comment: @Jukodan You should need no changes to the template.  Just add an entry to `/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts`.  This file may not exist yet, so you would need to created it.